# Remove loops from database structure

Tags: qlikview

I have two fact tables : Budget and vente .

I create a link table to store them but I get loops between tables as it's shown in the following picture .

[image]

How to remove loops ?

Comment: Looks like you're almost there. "Code Rayon" needs to be added to your key in `Budget` so that it doesn't associate between `Budget` and `Merchandise`.

Comment: I would concatenate Budget and Vente into a single Fact table. Then align all keys going out of those 2 tables. That way I would assume that you can discard the linktable too.

Comment: @seebach yes excact .

Comment: FYI, if you ever end up with data on a different grain in a new fact table that shares some of those keys, concatenating does not easily scale. But if this doesn't matter in your use-case, concatenation should work just fine.